# Determining 32/64 bit in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a couple lines of code that will pull from WMI if a machine is either 32/64 bit and then if it is 64 do this .... if it is 32bit do this...

Can anyone help?

Comment: `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem`

Answer (score 32):

There's two boolean static methods in the Environment you can inspect and compare, one looks at the PowerShell process, one looks at the underlying OS.

```
if ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess -ne [Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
"PowerShell process does not match the OS"
}
```

Comment: This variable is not available in older environments, e.g., Powershell 2.0 on Windows 7.  @Guvante's answer seems to work.

Comment: @dmattp [`Is64BitProcess`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.is64bitprocess) and [`Is64BitOperatingSystem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem) were introduced with .NET 4.0 — first utilized by PowerShell 3.0 — whereas the [`Win32_OperatingSystem` WMI class](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem) was introduced with Vista/Server 2008.  On older systems one could [implement the same logic](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,75feca36cdd83149) themselves.

Comment: On my 64-bit windows the `if` always fail, because both condition are `True`, the `-ne` should always fail here.   We should use `-or` here.

Answer (score 28):

[Random discussion about it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5dfeb3ab-6265-40cd-a4ac-05428b9db5c3/determine-32-or-64bit-os?forum=winserverpowershell)

Assuming you are running at least Windows 7, the following should work.

Including a sample that worked for me in a 32 bit version of powershell running on a 64 bit machine:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture
```

Returns "64-bit" for 64 bit.

```
if ((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture).osarchitecture -eq "64-bit")
{
    #64 bit logic here
    Write "64-bit OS"
}
else
{
    #32 bit logic here
    Write "32-bit OS"
}
```

Comment: Older OSes don't have an osarchitecture property, fwiw.

Comment: What are older OS's? We only have windows 7 and up

Comment: I think you're good, then.  Vista might have been the last one without it.

Comment: 64-bit isn't always guaranteed, I ran into a user who was getting "64 bits" as the response.

Comment: @QuickNull: Can you expand on that comment? This logic can totally fail to detect 64-bit (as mentioned in other comments) but I can't think of a situation where it would falsely detect 64-bit.

Comment: @Guvante Sure -- the text response "64-bit" isn't guaranteed.  So in the logic above, since it's looking specifically for that string might fail. I came across a user who was getting "64 bits" as the response so I had to change the logic to "if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture.Contains("64") -eq $true)"

Comment: this is not working on Win11 build 22622 x64 Fr with PS version is 5.1.22621.436

Comment: @NolmëInformatique: I inlined the alias in the answer that the link I provided used and got it to work on my Windows 11 machine

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to a previous answer but will get a correct result regardless of 64-bit/64_bit/64bit/64bits format.

```
if ((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture).osarchitecture -like "64*")
{
#64bit code here
Write "64-bit OS"
}
else
{
#32bit code here
Write "32-bit OS"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[IntPtr]::Size -eq 4 # 32 bit
```

The size of an IntPtr will be 4 bytes on a 32 bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx).

Comment: how would I put this into and if statement?

Comment: This only tells you what version of Powershell you are running. Pulled up a 32 bit window to verify.

Comment: "The size of an IntPtr will be 4 bytes on a 32 bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine" is incorrect.  This code checks if the _process_, not the _operating system_, is 32-bit.  See the linked documentation where it says (emphasis mine) "The size of a pointer or handle in **this process**, measured in bytes. The value of this property is 4 in a 32-bit **process**, and 8 in a 64-bit **process**."

Answer (score 2):

```
if($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq "x86"){"32-Bit CPU"}Else{"64-Bit CPU"}
```

-edit, sorry forgot to include more code to explain the usage.

```
if($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq "x86")
 {
#If the powershell console is x86, create alias to run x64 powershell console.
 set-alias ps64 "$env:windir\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

$script2=[ScriptBlock]::Create("#your commands here, bonus is the script block expands variables defined above")

ps64 -command $script2
 }
 Else{
 #Otherwise, run the x64 commands.
```

Comment: How would I put that into an if statement so i can put my code after 32 bit cpu and after 64 bit cpu.  I tried your line with no luck, although I am sure there is more to is

Comment: This returns true in a 32 bit version of powershell running on a 64 bit version of Windows.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to include the code for dealing with running in x64 or x86 powershell.

Comment: Will this be fine running on newer versions of windows ex.8.1

Comment: I don't think there would be any problems, as long as the Powershell environment variable `$env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` was available.

Comment: To echo @Guvante's comment, the `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` environment variable indicates the architecture of the _process_, not the _operating system_.  Further, according to [The 'Sysnative' folder in 64-bit Windows explained](https://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm) "The Sysnative folder is only available in a 64-bit Windows. A 32-bit Windows does not have any Sysnative folder.", so this code seems to assume it's differentiating between 32- and 64-bit processes specifically on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Two lines smashed togther for a nice one-liner:

```
Write-Host "64bit process?:"$([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) ;Write-Host "64bit OS?:"$([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is ***never*** necessary to filter a Boolean value (such as the value returned by the `-Eq` operator) through an “`If`” or to compare a Boolean value or expression to `$True` or `$False`.

[Jose's one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67691083/3789665) simplifies to:

```
$global:Is64Bits=(gwmi win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture).osarchitecture -eq "64-bit"
```