# How do I check the OS architecture(32 or 64 bit) using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am writing a Powershell script which will be integrated into a product designed for 32 bit Windows machines. So on invocation it will by default run on the x86 Powershell even on 64 bit machines.
I tried using `[System.IntPtr]::Size` but the output differs with the Powershell version on the same machine.

Powershell(32 bit) -

```
PS D:\powershellScripts>  [System.IntPtr]::Size    
4
```

Powershell(64 bit) on same machine-

```
PS D:\powershellScripts> [System.IntPtr]::Size
8
```

I need an independent solution which helps me distinguish the address size of the underlying machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining 32/64 bit in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977657/determining-32-64-bit-in-powershell)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon)'s link to a closely related question with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42495675/45375), the following concise solution is possible, which works from *both* 32-bit and 64-bit PowerShell sessions:

```
$pointerSizeInBytes = (4, 8)[[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem]
```

<sup>A `[bool]` value interpreted as an *array index* (`[int]`) maps to either `0` (`$false`) or `1` (`$true`), which is used here to select the appropriate value from array `4, 8`.</sup>

---

Here's the original form of the answer, which may have some related information of interest:

---

A simple test, assuming that you're *always* running from a 32-bit PowerShell instance:

```
$is64Bit = Test-Path C:\Windows\SysNative
```

<sup>32-bit processes (only) on 64-bit systems see the 64-bit SYSTEM32 (sic) directory as `C:\Windows\SysNative`</sup>

However, the following **works from *both* 32-bit and 64-bit sessions**:

```
$is64Bit = Test-Path 'Env:ProgramFiles(x86)'
```

<sup>Only on 64-bit systems does an automatically defined `ProgramFiles(x86)` environment variable exist alongside the `ProgramFiles` variable.</sup>

To **get the OS-native pointer size in bytes**:

```
$pointerSizeInBytes = (4, 8)[[bool] ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}]
```

<sup>`${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` uses [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) to return the value of env. var. `ProgramFiles(x86)` directly; casting a string value to `[bool]` returns `$true` only for *non-empty* strings; a `[bool]` interpreted as an *array index* (`[int]`) maps to either `0` (`$false`) or `1` (`$true`), which is used here to select the appropriate value from array `4, 8`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to wrap it inside a small helper function:

```
function Get-Architecture {
    # What bitness does Windows use
    $windowsBitness = switch ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {   # needs .NET 4
        $true  { 64; break }
        $false { 32; break }
        default {
            (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -replace '\D'
            # Or do any of these:
            # (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -replace '\D' -replace '86', '32'
            # (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).AddressWidth   # slow...
        }
    }

    # What bitness does this PowerShell process use
    $processBitness = [IntPtr]::Size * 8
    # Or do any of these:
    # $processBitness = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -replace '\D' -replace '86', '32'
    # $processBitness = if ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) { 64 } else { 32 }

    # Return the info as object
    return New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        'ProcessArchitecture' = "{0} bit" -f $processBitness
        'WindowsArchitecture' = "{0} bit" -f $windowsBitness
    }
}

Get-Architecture
```

This will return both the 'bitness' of the currently running PowerShell process aswell as the bitness of the OS like:

```
ProcessArchitecture WindowsArchitecture
------------------- -------------------
64 bit              64 bit
```