# Powershell DbaTools Encryption

Tags: powershell, dbatools

I have been using the DbaTools module in Powershell for years with no issue. However this morning I can no longer connect to any database due to the error `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)`. I did some research and I saw several posts about it being an issue with 32-bit compatibility with 64-bit. At the moment it appears to only affect my local machine, and our automated scripts are running normally on their dedicated servers.

After rebooting and trying again I got this error message, which did not appear before:
[image]

The dbatools.io/newdefaults URL in the message redirects you [this article](https://blog.netnerds.net/2023/03/new-defaults-for-sql-server-connections-encryption-trust-certificate/). I do not have permission to create certificates on my local machine, and changing the defaults with `Set-DbatoolsConfig` did not fix the error.

The dbatools version was 2.1.4. Using Powershell 7.3.8 gave me the error. I reverted back to dbatools 1.1.42, but am still getting the same error. Using Powershell 5.1 with dbatools 1.1.42 I am able to connect perfectly fine.

Has anybody else encountered this error, or knows of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody finding this later, I found out it was a me problem. A few weeks ago I installed the newest PSVersion, 7.3.8, and accidentally installed the x86 version.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977657/determining-32-64-bit-in-powershell) StackOverflow post about the same issue, and it showed some commands to run to check your OS.

```
[Environment]::Is64BitProcess
[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem
```

Running that in the command line told me the process (Powershell) was not the same as the OS. I installed the 64-bit version from Microsoft using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.3). Once I installed the correct Powershell I was able to get it working. Hopefully this helps somebody in the future.